# Automatically post form to another URL

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, http-post, postback

I'm working with a payment page that requires me to post form data to it. I know how to post my form to a different page using a button's PostBackUrl property, and I know how to automatically submit a form so it posts back to itself onload, but I can't figure out how to combine the two.

I have a form that in OnLoad sets the values of a bunch of hidden fields to post to the payment page. When it loads, I want it to automatically post to the payment page without the user having to click a button. If I set the Form's Action property in Page_Load, I get a "Validation of viewstate MAC failed" error. I've seen this before when modifying the contents of a server control client-side then posting back. But here I've set the Action server-side and I'm not even posting back to the page so how can does it validate the viewstate?

I've just discovered that if I place a Button on the page with the same PostBackUrl as I set the Action to, this error goes away and it works, so I guess that's a work around, but can anyone explain the error and/or suggest a better way of auto posting the form to a different URL when the page loads?

EDIT:
Here is my testing code as I currently have it:

Intermediate page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPostData" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="hidden" name="<%# Eval("key") %>" value="<%# Eval("value") %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="" 
    PostBackUrl="http://localhost:64545/Payment.aspx" Style="visibility:hidden"/>
</form>
```

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) //(Should never post back)
        {
            //this.form1.Method = "post";
            this.form1.Action = "http://localhost:64545/Payment.aspx";

            Dictionary<string, string> postData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            postData.Add(_accountIDKey, "555555");
            postData.Add(_amountKey, "125.75");
            postData.Add(_referenceIDKey, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            postData.Add(_accountDataKey, "{'FirstName':'John','LastName':'Sleevenstein','Address1':'123 Fake St.'}");
            postData.Add(_returnUrlKey, Request.RawUrl);    //This should be a receipt page
            postData.Add(_hashKey, CreateHash(postData));

            rptPostData.DataSource = postData;
            rptPostData.DataBind();

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(WebForm1), "PostScript", "document.form1.submit();", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have me seriously confused. Why are you posting the form after the form itself has loaded? Wouldn't this cause a full page refresh? I think it would help to see the code for the form.

Comment: @zerkey Not a refresh, but a redirect. The flow would be you click checkout on a shopping cart page -> redirected to this intermediate page which loads a form with relevant data to post to a payment page on a different website -> form automatically posts to and displays payment page. It's my understanding that posting the form client side is the only way to redirect to the page the form is posting to. The line where I set form1.Action gets results in the exception unless I put the button with the RedirectUrl on the form. I'm uncomfortable with that since I don't know exactly why it's working.